# Sitecore LaunchPad is distorted after deploying Web Application on Azure PaaS

Tags: paas, deployment

I have deployed our application on Azure Pass. I am able to login into the Sitecore CMS and be redirected to the LaunchPad. LaunchPad CSS is distorted and the click is not working.

[image]

Also, there are a lot of 401 errors in developers' tools for CSS and JS files.

When I ran link: https://<>/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/LaunchPad/LaunchPad.css

I am getting error as "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Please note we are using Form authentication as we have integrated the site with Azure B2C AD. If We remove form authentication then the site does work.

can someone help me on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formauthentication with azure adb2c , why though , just use federated auth , why to complicate stuff

Comment: Thanks Abhay. We removed form authentication and did it work.